# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'split')"

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

how to perform "split" test with Angular ?

I'm trying to run a test on a method that has a "split" but I end up getting this error

follow below method , and test class spec.ts

```
  getCellData(row: any, column: any): any {
    const nestedProperties: string[] = column.property.split('.');
    let value: any = row;
    for (const prop of nestedProperties) {
      value = value[prop];
    }
    return value;
  }
```

```
 fdescribe('getCellData:', () => {
      const column: any = [{
        property: 'address.street',
        label: 'Rua',
        type: 'boolean',
      }];

      const columnItem: any =[{
        name: 'teste',
        address:{
          street: 'Rua dos Alfeneiros, nº 4'
        }
      }]
     
      let value: any = columnItem;
    
      it('teste A', () => {
        const nestedProperties: string[] = column.property.split('.');
        expect(component.getCellData(column, value)).toEqual(nestedProperties);

      });
    });
```

Comment: Why have you repeated the line `const nestedProperties: string[] = column.property.split('.');` in the implementation and the test? And why type everything as `any`? That's not actually what the thing you're trying to to test returns anyway, because it processes it further. Also note you're passing `column` to the `row` parameter and `value` to the `column` parameter, which doesn't seem consistent. And finally `value` is an _array_, which doesn't have a `property` property to `.split`.

Answer (score 0):

The object you're passing to getCellData is an array of objects, so if you want to read the property value on an element in the array you have to index the array properly:

```
const nestedProperties: string[] = column[0].property.split('.');
```

However, it looks like you've mixed up the order of arguments in the function call. I think you meant to call the function like this:

```
component.getCellData(value, column)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.